Unity Node-Based Dialogue System: Line Renderer Issues Connecting Nodes
I want to create a node-based dialogue system in unity UI. The hierarchy of my node object is as follows:

The parent object has a script that stores the node data. It includes:

GUIDText: Displays the node's GUIDs.
NodeText: An InputField for adding text to the node.
Add button: Instantiates a response GameObject to connect nodes.
responsesTransform: Holds the responses.

Additionally, the nodes look like this:

I want to draw a line from the responders to the nodes using a LineRenderer, but I'm having trouble with the positioning. The code for connecting the nodes to each other is as follows:
public class ConnectNodes : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GraphicRaycaster raycaster; 
    public EventSystem eventSystem;

    private GameObject currentNode;
    private GameObject targetNode;

    public GameObject linePrefab;
    public Transform canvas;


    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            GetResponseElement();
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            GetNodeElement();

            if (currentNode != null && targetNode != null && currentNode != targetNode)
            {
                var currentNodeResponse = currentNode.GetComponent<ResponseGameObject>();
                var targetNodeComponent = targetNode.GetComponent<NodeGameObject>();

                if (currentNodeResponse != null && targetNodeComponent != null)
                {
                    if (!currentNodeResponse.nodeData.NextNodes.Contains(targetNodeComponent.nodeData))
                    {
                        currentNodeResponse.nodeData.NextNodes.Add(targetNodeComponent.nodeData);
                    }

                    Vector3 currentConnectPointPos = currentNode.GetComponentInParent<RectTransform>().position;
                    Vector3 targetConnectPointPos = targetNodeComponent.GetComponent<RectTransform>().position;
                    GameObject lineGameobject = Instantiate(linePrefab,canvas);
                    lineGameobject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
                    LineRenderer line = lineGameobject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
                    line.SetPosition(0, currentConnectPointPos);
                    line.SetPosition(1,targetConnectPointPos);
                    Debug.Log($"Connected {currentNodeResponse.nodeData.NodeGUID} to {targetNodeComponent.nodeData.NodeGUID}");
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.LogError("Either currentNode or targetNode does not have the expected components!");
                }
            }

            currentNode = null;
            targetNode = null;
        }

    }

    void GetResponseElement()
    {
        PointerEventData pointerEventData = new PointerEventData(eventSystem);
        pointerEventData.position = Input.mousePosition;

        List<RaycastResult> results = new List<RaycastResult>();

        raycaster.Raycast(pointerEventData, results);

        foreach (RaycastResult result in results)
        {
            ResponseGameObject response = result.gameObject.GetComponent<ResponseGameObject>();

            if (response != null)
            {
                currentNode = response.gameObject;
                Debug.Log("response found: " + response.name);
            }
        }
    }

    void GetNodeElement()
    {
        PointerEventData pointerEventData = new PointerEventData(eventSystem);
        pointerEventData.position = Input.mousePosition;

        List<RaycastResult> results = new List<RaycastResult>();

        raycaster.Raycast(pointerEventData, results);

        foreach (RaycastResult result in results)
        {
            NodeGameObject node = result.gameObject.GetComponent<NodeGameObject>();

            if (node != null)
            {
                targetNode = node.gameObject;
                Debug.Log("node found: " + node.name);
            }

        }
    }

}

I hope I have been clear. Thank you in advance for your help.
I tried using local positions, but it seems they are relative to the parent, so I didn't get any results. I also attempted to use transform.position instead of RectTransform, but that didn't work either.

Note that RectTransform.position == transform.position (RectTransform is derived from transform) the main issue is probably that UI is in screen pixel space while LineRenderer in 3D world space coordinates

I have programmed a Line Renderer for physic based game. Let me know about the exact problem what are you using is it 3D line or 2D Canvas type. How you are mapping positions ?

Thanks for the reply! I'm using a 2D Canvas for my dialogue system, and the Line Renderer is supposed to draw lines between nodes in the UI. The issue is with mapping positions. Since I'm working in a canvas, I think the RectTransform coordinates don't align properly with transform.position. I tried using local positions relative to the parent, but the lines aren't showing as expected.
